# Получить имя изображения загружаемого с помощью input[type="file"]

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как с помощью регулярных выражений или другим способ получить имя изображения, загружаемого с помощью `input[type="file"]`. Например, скачиваем картинку, полное имя будет например такое: `C:\fakepath\jbat006 (1).jpg`.

Цифра `1` в скобках появляется если скачиваем одно и то же изображение 2 раза.

Как оставить только `jbat006`? Сам путь отсекается так `val.replace(/.*[\/\\]/, '')`, как вместе с тем, избавиться еще от правой части (`" (1).jpg"`).

Comment: Вам имя файла нужно на сервере или на клиентской части?

Comment: клиентская часть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете получить имя файла из самого инпута. Подробнее можно почитать [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/file). Вообще, мне кажется, что тут можно обойтись и без регулярок, но ниже решение с ними.

```js
let pattern = /((?:.(?!\(\d+\)))+.)(?:\(\d+\))?\..+/
document.querySelector('.input').onchange = function(){
  document.querySelector('.preview')
  .textContent = this.files[0].name.match(pattern)[1]
}
```

```html
<input type='file' class='input'>
<div class='preview'></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! я у меня с регулярками пока туго

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать

```js
var val = "C:\\fakepath\\jbat006 (1).jpg";
console.log(val.replace(/^.*[\/\\]| \(\d+\)\.\w+$/g, ''));
// => jbat006
```

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `.*[\/\\]` - 0 и более символов, отличных от символов перевода строки, как можно больше, до последнего `\` or `/` в строке
- `|` - или
- `(` -  строка  `(`
- `\d+` - 1 и более цифр
- `\)\.` - строка `).`
- `\w+` -  1 и более букв/цифр/_
- `$` - конец строки